# Prove intersection of two cyclic submodule is zero $(m)\cap(n) = 0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Sorry for the siily question:

Let $M$ be a $R$ module ,where $R$ is a commutative ring, let $(m)$ and $(n)$ be two cyclic submodule of $M$ with $\text{ann}(m) = \mathfrak{p}$ a prime ideal ,and $\text{ann}(n) = \mathfrak{q}$ , such that $\mathfrak{p} \ne \mathfrak{q}$.

Prove $(m)\cap(n) = 0$

---

My attempt if $rm = sn \ne 0$ for some $r,s \in R$ then pick $t \in \mathfrak{q}\setminus \mathfrak{p}$ , then we have $tsn =0 = trm$ , I want to deduce contradiction, however although $tm \ne 0$, it's not clear $trm \ne 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u are on the right track,since $trm=0$,$tr\in P$,Now $P$ is prime,so either $t\in P$ or $r\in P$,this implies that $r\in P$,i.e $rm=0=sn$,that is the intersection is trivial.